# import data into mongodb databse from .csv file in windows

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose

I have `mongodb` running in remote `ubuntu server` say `IP:192.168.2.10 and Port:27017`. I access `mongodb` through `mongoose` and `node.js`. Now I want to import data from `.csv` to `mongodb`. I know about `mongoImport` but I have no idea how to use it from `windows` and where to start in `windows`. I have installed node.js and mongoose using npm in my windows system. I read about `mongoImport` says it should run from command prompt. In windows cmd prompt when I run

```
mongoimport --host 192.168.2.10 --port 27017 --collection Attributes --db Master --file <P:\Attributes.csv
```

I get this error.

> ReferenceError: mongoimport is not defined

Should I install mongodb in windows, I don't think so. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will have to get mongodb executable in windows.

After getting that, go to the bin directory in your mongodb installation and you will find the mongoimport.exe there.

Execute your command from there.

Comment: so I need to install mongodb in my system?

Comment: Yes. And then go to the bin folder and execute mongoimport.

Comment: I don't had to install mongodb in windows, I had to download `.zip` file and did as @LalitAgarwal said

Answer (score 4):

The primary mistake people do is try to import the csv file by issuing the mongoimport command while they are inside mongo Shell. The correct way of doing it is outside mongo shell. And ensure that you have the binary that you are trying to execute. In this case it is "mongoimport".